# Miracle Java Impossible Code?

Tags: java, debugging

Here is a code from one of my programming competition, it is messy and I have not changed anything. Just show you the miracle.

**MainClass.java**

```
import java.util.*;

public class MainClass {

    private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Scanner scanText = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static int[][] list;
    private static int row, col;

    private static int lazyCode = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        col = scan.nextInt();
        row = scan.nextInt();

        list = new int[row][col];
        for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
                list[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> lazyList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>();

        String line = scanText.nextLine();
        Scanner temp_scan = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter(",");

        while (temp_scan.hasNext()) {

            String str = temp_scan.next().toString();

            char isLazy = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);

            if (isLazy == '*') {

                lazyList.add(new ArrayList<Point>());
                Point p = findNextSeat();

                int lc = lazyCode;
                list[p.r][p.c] = lc + 10;
                lazyList.get(lc).add(p);
                lazyCode++;

            } else {

                char character = str.charAt(0);
                int temp = character - 65;
                int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(1)) - 1;
                System.out.println();// ------------------------BreakPointHere
                int x = list[temp][temp2];// ------------------------BreakPointHere
                System.out.println();// ------------------------BreakPointHere
                if (x == 0) {
                    list[temp][temp2] = 1;
                } else {
                    Point p = findNextSeat();

                    int lc = list[temp][temp2] - 10;
                    list[temp][temp2] = 1;
                    list[p.r][p.c] = lc + 10;
                    lazyList.get(lc).add(p);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lazyList.size(); ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lazyList.get(i).size(); ++j) {
                Point p1 = lazyList.get(i).get(j);
                char c1 = (char) (p1.c + 65);
                if (i == lazyList.size() - 1 && j == lazyList.get(i).size() - 1) {
                    System.out.print(c1 + p1.r + ",");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(c1 + p1.r);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static class Point {
        Point(int i1, int i2) {
            r = i1;
            c = i2;
        }
        int r;
        int c;
    }

    private static Point findNextSeat() {
        for (int r = 0; r < row; ++r) {
            for (int c = 0; c < col; ++c) {

                if (list[r][c] == 0) {
                    return new Point(r, c);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Input :

> 2
>
> 9
>
> A1,A4,A6,B1

Note : 
For Input, I cannot give you the real input from contest because they do not allow us to do it, so I just give some worked input.

In Eclipse,
See my "BreakPoint", break at those lines, and debug it, first iterate is OK. BUT, IN SECOND ITERATION, THE SECOND LINE OF BREAK POINT WOULD RUN TWICE!!! TWICE!!! AND THEN THROW THE EXCEPTION. YES, THE MIDDLE CODE WOULD RUN TWICE!!!
And I am working on this unbelievable problem for the whole competition. I have programmed for 7 years, It is the first time in my life see such great epic unknown bug.

Comment: It is a competition, so the code maybe messy and unreadable, but just pay  attention on that BUG!  I use Eclipse Luna with jdk1.8.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "THE SECOND LINE OF BREAK POINT WOULD RUN TWICE". Putting it in caps doesn't make it clearer, it just looks like you're shouting. Please format the code properly, clarify the code, and ideally reduce it to a [mcve]. Additionally, explain whether this is just behaviour seen in the Eclipse debugger or whether there's some unexpected output.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: It's a computer I don't think it's going to do anything you don't tell it to.

Comment: If the eclipse debugger is not using the latest version of the code, stepping through may show you this type of behaviour.  Also you are probably getting an Array Out of Bounds error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly have the option **Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions** in **Window > Preferences > Java > Debug** activated, so the debugger stops two times on your line: one time because of the breakpoint, one time because of the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Millions of thanks. You are correct, this is the problem of "Debugger Setting". I finish this question within 30 minutes, and remaining 2hour 30 minutes are work on this "debugger problem".